# If $x_n \to x$ with $x >0$ then is it true that $nx_n \to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $x_n \to x$ with $x >0$ then is it true that $nx_n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: So, eventually, $x_n>x/2>0$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that  by definition of limit, notably by $\epsilon < \frac12$, eventually

$$0<\frac x 2<x_n <\frac 3 2x$$

therefore eventually

$$nx_n>n\frac x 2 \to \infty$$

by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x/2 > \epsilon >0$.

There exists a $n_0$ s.t. for $n \ge n_0$:

$0< x-\epsilon < x/2 < x_n < x+\epsilon$, and

$0<n(x/2) < nx_n$ ;

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} nx_n= \infty$, comparison test.

P.S. Can you show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(x/2) = \infty$?(Archimedean principle)